# Sql query to get 1 from each column row wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
  1        Null       Null
  Null      1         Null
  Null     Null         1
```

Sql query to get 1 from each column row wise.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you mean by "get 1 from each column row wise". I assume what you're showing us is meant to be *sample data*? If so, what's the *expected result*? Also, probably need to add more *variety* to the sample data since it seems quite uniform. Please [edit] and add more explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need all 1's from above table in one column as output row wise. Below query is working perfectly both row wise and column wise.Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but so would the query `select 1 from Table`. I wanted to establish what the possible *variations* were which your sample data fails to show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function for each row:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Column1, Column2, Column3)
FROM ...
```

And with [MAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql) for every column:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(Column1) as Column1,
    MAX(Column2) as Column2,
    MAX(Column3) as Column3
FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

With NVL and NVL2 function for each row

Using NVL2:-

```
select Nvl2(column1,column1,Nvl2(colume2,column2,column3)) from table;
```

Using NVL:-

```
select nvl(nvl(column1,colume2),column3) from table;
```

Comment: `NVL` & `NVL2` are `ORACLE` functions, and the question is related to `SQL Server`.